# Strings retrieved from files displaying garbage

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I have 2 files, `easyp.txt` and `easyn.txt`, were `easyp.txt` stores points, and `easyn.txt` stores names. I have code that displays the top score and the players name. It was working fine, then I edited some other lines, and upon running again, it spews out rubbish. The codes look like this:

```
case 1:
        infile.open("easyn.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        ofile.open("easyp.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        while (getline(infile, STRINGT) && getline(ofile, STRINGO))
        {
            istringstream buffer(STRINGO);
            buffer >> value;
            if (infile.eof() && ofile.eof()){
                printf("The top player for easy is %s with only %i tries!", STRINGD, value);
                break;
            }
            if (value < best)
            {
                STRINGD = STRINGT;
                best = value;
            }
        }
        infile.close();
        ofile.close();
        _getch();
        break;
```

(lower number of points is better btw)

When I run the program it outputs random ascii characters as the player name, and `1835884884` as the score.

Yes I am `using namespace std`

The only other time I have file reading/writing is in the following:

```
            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open("easyn.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                myfile << chName << "\n";
                myfile.close();
            }
            myfile.open("easyp.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                myfile << iTurns << "\n";
                myfile.close();
            }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you opening the files for writing but then reading them?

Comment: `ios::out | ios::app` these are write flags. Why are you setting them for input files?

Comment: I have later down the code, in an entirely diffrent switch open for writing

Comment: I just removed those and it didn't change :/

Comment: Can you get something I can compile and run in one go that shows the issue?

Comment: What do you see when you run this in a debugger? Are you getting valid values? Invalid values? Which line?

Comment: almost done, had to do something else

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Rajz7XP That is a basic program were you input two sets of names and points, and it should sort them, but it fails.

Comment: sorry it took so long, im using a tracpad and a crappy keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your program is this:

```
printf("The top player for easy is %s with only %i tries!", STRINGD, value);
```

The `%s` format specifier to `printf` expects a `char *`, not a `std::string`. What you want to do to fix that is replace `STRINGD` with `STRINGD.c_str()`.

Passing an argument to a varargs function of another type than the function expects to receive invokes undefined behavior. Exactly what happens depends on your architecture and ABI, so I can't really give a detailed explanation about that without such details, but I don't think that matters much anyway. :)

Comment: okay, it fixed it, but then when I run it again (i didnt change anything) it just prints nothing. any ideas?

Comment: @squid1: Well, I can't speak of your original program since you haven't posted the entire sourcecode, but in the code on your pastebin, you initialized `best` to 0, so unless some score is less than zero, then `if (value < best)` is never going to trigger. Also, it is not unlikely that `infile.eof()` is going to return false until you actually try to read through the EOF.

Comment: that is actaully just an error in my pastebin program, in my real program i have `best = 10000`. And what the `infile.eof()` is supposed to return false, because I only want it displaying the scores once it checks the whole files

Comment: Yes, but my point is that as long as your `getline()` calls return true, then `eof()` is going to return false. Just place the `printf()` after the `while` loop instead of using that condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help's but instead of using the `.txt` extension, use the `.dat` extension. Maybe it would help?

`.dat` files are `"data files"` that can be opened by text editors, so I though this might help >_>

and I'd try not use `ios::out | ios::app`, even if you do use them, your doing it wrong. check here if you wanna fix that -> [fileStreaming C++ tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm), mostly because you'd use `ios::out | ios::in` in most cases.

And you could use other things besides `while (getline(infile, STRINGT) && getline(ofile, STRINGO))` personally I'd never use that, mostly because it's just my preference.